# Pass enum as parameter from C# to C/C++

Tags: c#, c++, enums, interop, marshalling

I have a C/C++ DLL defined below:

```
#ifdef COMPILING_LIBCTMCLIENT
#define LIBCTMCLIENT_FUNC LIBCTMCLIENT_C_LINKAGE __declspec(dllexport)

LIBCTMCLIENT_FUNC
struct CTMDownloadCMDataResult ctm_download_cm_data(const char * 
szCmTransactionId, enum CTMCMOperationType cm_type);

enum CTMCMOperationType {
    CTM_CM_NONE = 0,
    CTM_CM_LOAN,
    CTM_CM_PICKUP,
    CTM_CM_BALANCE
};
```

I defined my C# application below:

```
[DllImport("libctmclient-0.dll", EntryPoint = "ctm_download_cm_data", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern CTMDownloadCMDataResult DownloadCMData([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string cmTransactionId, CTMCMOperationType cmType);

public enum CTMCMOperationType
{
    CTM_CM_NONE = 0,
    CTM_CM_LOAN,
    CTM_CM_PICKUP,
    CTM_CM_BALANCE
};
```

Tried calling DownloadCMData as shown below:

```
CTMCMOperationType cmType = CTMCMOperationType.CTM_CM_LOAN;
string cmTransactionId = "123456789";
CTMDownloadCMDataResult result = DownloadCMData(cmTransactionId, cmType);
```

But ended up with a MarshalDirectiveException.
Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible.

I'm pretty sure the string parameter is working but it's the first time I'm passing an enum so I am most likely pointing it as the problem.

I'm guessing that you can't just pass an enum directly from a managed code like C# to an unmanaged code like C/C++.

Is there something I need to do or do I need to use integer/long instead?

Comment: Yes, first try changing return type and parameters to int and see if that works, then short and long and heck even byte.  Keep track of the exceptions you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably an issue with the struct you return.
Something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293593/how-do-i-call-this-c-function-in-c-sharp-unmarshalling-return-struct).

Comment: is CTMDownloadCMDataResult a struct? if so show its code

Comment: The problem was not the enum after all but it was the struct. Thank you for all your help!